# Detect HTML5's autofocus feature with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, autofocus

I perform an action with jQuery every time a textfield is focused on my website. Everything works fine as long as I manually focus on the textfield by clicking on it.

However: I'm using HTML5's autofocus feature, and jQuery doesn't detect that a textfield automatically has been focused. How can I make sure that my script performs an action whether a textfield has been manually or automatically focused?

Right now, I'm using...

```
$("input:text, input:password").focus(function() { });
```

... to detect when a textfield is highlighted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only need to worry about autofocus on the initial page load then maybe something like this?

Trigger the focus event on autofocus'd elements on pageload:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
  $("input:text, input:password").focus(function () { });//attach the focus event

  $('input[autofocus]').trigger('focus');//force fire it on the autofocus element
});
</script>
```

Comment: Simple, elegant, and totally solved the problem. Thanks, Jake!